# Angular Nested GroupBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a nested groupBy in Angular.  For whatever reason (I haven't been able to figure out why), the "normal" (key,value) method does not work for me.  The page is always blank.  The only method I have been able to get to work to group it by QuestionClusterID is as follows.  Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eZE3VAPEpLyCo87QWXIl?p=preview) of how I tried to get it to work with the Sections.

In my controller:

```
$scope.questionsToFilter = function () {
    indexedQuestions = [];
    return $scope.questions;
}
$scope.filterQuestions = function (question) {
    var questionIsNew = indexedQuestions.indexOf(question.QuestionClusterID) == -1;
    if (questionIsNew) {
        indexedQuestions.push(question.QuestionClusterID);
    }
    return questionIsNew;
}
```

In my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="cluster in questionsToFilter() | filter:filterQuestions">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @*Question Section*@
            <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:{QuestionClusterID: cluster.QuestionClusterID}">
```

The above method works perfectly.  The problem now is that I have to add another grouping level and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I need to groupBy QuestionSectionID then by QuestionClusterID.

I tried writing similar functions to get the sections:

```
$scope.filterSections = function (section) {
    var sectionIsNew = indexedSections.indexOf(section.QuestionSectionID) == -1;
    if (sectionIsNew) {
        indexedSections.push(section.QuestionSectionID);
    }
    return sectionIsNew;
}
$scope.sectionsToFilter = function () {
    indexedSections = [];
    return $scope.editablequestions;
}
```

This works to pull out the Sections, I can't figure out how to then "push" the Clusters into each Section.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a Plunker sample?

Comment: Here is a Plunker that shows how it works with 1 GroupBy (by QuestionClusterID https://plnkr.co/edit/eZE3VAPEpLyCo87QWXIl?p=preview.  I need to figure out how to do it with the second (by QuestionsSectionID.  I needs to group first by QuestionsSectionID then by QuestionClusterID.